# Deleteing rows without a loop meeting certain criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on writing a macro that deletes all rows that are less than .75 from a value I found using a formula.  In another thread, on here, I found a loop that works, but this takes a lot of time to run... so I am trying to find a way without a loop.  So far, I have the code as seen below, but i get a "run-time error 1004, method 'range of object worksheet' failed" on the line

```
ws.Range(Left(rowsToDelete, Len(rowsToDelete) - 1)).Select
```

Anybody have any ideas on a correction? All help is appreciated

```
Private Sub CommandButton6_Click()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i&, lr&, rowsToDelete$, lookFor$, lookFor2$

'*!!!* set the condition for row deletion
lookFor = "#VALUE!"
lookFor2 = "0.75"

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Entry")
lr = ws.Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

ReDim arr(0)

For i = 1 To lr
 If StrComp(CStr(ws.Range("H" & i).Text), lookFor, vbTextCompare) = 0 Or _
    CDbl(ws.Range("H" & i).Value) < CDbl(lookFor2) Then
    ReDim Preserve arr(UBound(arr) + 1)
    arr(UBound(arr) - 1) = i
 End If
Next i

If UBound(arr) > 0 Then
    ReDim Preserve arr(UBound(arr) - 1)
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        rowsToDelete = rowsToDelete & arr(i) & ":" & arr(i) & ","
    Next i

    ws.Range(Left(rowsToDelete, Len(rowsToDelete) - 1)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

    lr = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    ws.Range(lr & ":" & lr).Select
Else
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "No more rows contain: " & lookFor & "or" & lookFor2 & ", therefore exiting"
    Exit Sub
End If

If Not Application.ScreenUpdating Then Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Set ws = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: you could use specialcells to grab any formula error cells and delete the rows in one hit then use an autofilter and delete the .75 rows in another hit (using the .Text property is slow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
Sub Macro1()

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

    Dim r As Range

    Set r = Sheet1.UsedRange

    r.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="<.75", _
        Operator:=xlAnd
    r.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    r.AutoFilter

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .EnableEvents = True
End With

End Sub
```

This assumes that column H (or 8 in the code above) holds the value you want to filter for.  You'll have to adjust to fit your sheet.

Comment: this correctly found the rows I need it to find, but didn't delete all of the rows.  Does it make a difference that the values come from a formula? There are still rows with #Ref! and #Value! left over.

Comment: @Mike Ah...my guess is that #Ref! and #Value! aren't less than .75.  Let me fiddle with I can come up with...

Comment: I found another category to filter by to solve the issue of the leftover cells so the macro is working correctly(in column b).  I appreciate the help!

Comment: @Mike I know it's a bit of a hack, but would it be possible to wrap your formulas in a "IFERROR" statement (if 2007 or greater) or "ISERROR" (if earlier than 2007)? if it is an error, setting the value to something impossible like -9999 would then be captured by the autofilter macro I posted above?  As far as I can tell, autofilter can't filter out the error cells.

Comment: I used your same autofilter to just filter a different column for the correct rows I needed to delete( sorry i noticed this after I already asked), the program is running perfectly now.

Comment: @Mike No worries. the main thing is you've got it working as expected.  Good luck with the rest of your project!

Comment: You could have simply used r.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors).EntireRow.Delete Before the filter.